# How to wrap particular multiple divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just trying to work with jQuery wrapInner and I could not wrap particular multiple divs with a outer div.

```js
$('#outer').not('#inner3')
  .wrapInner('<div id="wrapper" style="background:green;"></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner1'>1</div>
  <div id='inner2'>2</div>
  <div id='inner3'>3</div>
</div>
```

How to wrap inner1 and inner2 within another div. I tried like above but this wraps whole 3 inner divs.

**Output required**:

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id="wrapper" style="background:green;">
    <div id='inner1'>1</div>
    <div id='inner2'>2</div>
  </div>
  <div id='inner3'>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.wrapAll()` function:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#outer div').not('#inner3')
    .wrapAll('<div id="hey" style="background:green;"></div>');
});
```

Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) link for more info.

From the documentation:

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.
>
> **.wrapAll( wrappingElement )**
>
> *wrappingElement*
>
> Type: Selector or htmlString or Element or jQuery
>
> A selector, element, HTML string, or jQuery object specifying the structure to wrap around the matched elements.
>
> **.wrapAll( function )**
>
> *function*
>
> Type: Function( Integer index ) => String or jQuery
>
> A callback function returning the HTML content or jQuery object to wrap around the matched elements. Receives the index position of the element in the set as an argument. Within the function, this refers to the current element in the se

Answer (score 3):

Try `$('#outer div').not('#inner3')`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#outer div').not('#inner3')
        .wrapInner('<div id="hey" style="background:green;"></div>');
});
```

<kbd>[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/WFenR/10)</kbd>

---

`$('#outer div').not('#inner3')` select all div inside element with id `outer` but not with element with id `inner3`

---

if you want two put first two children you can use `:lt()`

<kbd>[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/WFenR/9)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#outer div:lt(2)')
        .wrapInner('<div id="hey" style="background:green;"></div>');
});
```

---

**Update after OP's comment**

<kbd>[Updated fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/WFenR/7)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#outer div').not('#inner3')
        .wrapAll('<div id="hey" style="background:green;"></div>');
});
```

Comment: It does not work for me. It wraps all the available inner div except inner3. I want to wrap inner1 and inner2 with div wrapper. Check the updated question.

Comment: I am just posting a example case. My actual scenario is different and the div will have dynamic IDs, so as will be their IDs.

Answer (score 0):

To complete [Tushar Gupta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20393760/86072) :

```
// wrapInner will add a div *inside each selected node*
$('#outer1 div').not('#inner13')
        .wrapInner('<div id="hey1" style="background:green;"></div>');

// wrap will add one wrapper around *each selected node*
$('#outer2 div').not('#inner23')
        .wrap('<div id="hey2" style="background:green;"></div>');

// to create one single wrapper, and put the divs you want inside,
// you can do as follows :
$('<div id="hey3" style="background:green;"></div>')
    .append( $('#outer3 div').not('#inner33') )
    .prependTo('#outer3');
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WFenR/3/)

Comment: Thanks but what have you done ? I don't have outer2. And I want to wrap inner1 and inner2 with div wrapper. Check the updated question.